# ComponentDidMount doesn't see parent's props

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm stuck again. I'm trying to map my array to create new array of objects inside of my child component. Here's my issue - my method componentDidMount gets executed before data came from parents props, and my state stays empty. When I'm console.loging this.props and the end of componentDidMount I receive empty array, but when I'm console.loging it on render method it gives me 4 empty arrays, then it fills in to expected 300. What I'm doing wrong?

Parent component:

```
import "./App.css";
import { CompanyList } from "./components/companylist/companylist.component";
import { Searchfield } from "./components/searchfield/searchfield.component";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            companies: [],
            searchfield: "",
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const URL = "https://xxxxx/companies";
        fetch(URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => this.setState({ companies: data }))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error", error);
            });
    };

    render() {
        const filteredCompanies = this.state.companies.filter((item) =>
            item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <Searchfield
                    handleChange={(e) => this.setState({ searchfield: e.target.value })}
                />
                <CompanyList companies={filteredCompanies} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Children component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Company } from "../company/company.component";

export class CompanyList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            newArray: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const filledArray = this.props.companies.map((item) => {
            let result;
            fetch(`https://xxxxx/incomes/${item.id}`)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    let transactionsToFloat = data.incomes.map((item) =>
                        parseFloat(item.value)
                    );
                    result = transactionsToFloat.reduce((acc, num) => {
                        return acc + num;
                    }, 0);
                    result = Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
                });
            return {
                id: item.id,
                name: item.name,
                city: item.city,
                totalIncome: result,
            };
        });
        this.setState({ newArray: filledArray });
        console.log(this.props);
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> Id </th>
                            <th> Name </th>
                            <th> City </th>
                            <th> Total income </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    {this.props.companies.map((item) => (
                        <Company key={item.id} company={item} />
                    ))}
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you logged `filteredCompanies` to make sure it has data?

Comment: it has, when I'm sending data straight from props, it displays. But I need to calculate some more, then it breaks

Comment: You could check on `componentDidMount` to make sure that `companies` has data before trying to map over it.

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't. It doesn't see companies in this componentDidMount at all. As @Sandro Cagara Github said, it's because of react methods executing order. But I don't have any idea how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

> componentWillMount() happens before render(). componentDidMount() happens after.

This is happening because of how React works fundamentally. React is supposed to feel fast, fluent and snappy. the application should never get logged up with http requests or asynchronous code. The answer is to use the lifecycle methods to control the DOM.

What does it mean when a component mounts?

It might be helpful to understand some of the React vocabularies a little better. When a component is mounted it is being inserted into the DOM. This is when a constructor is called. componentWillMount is pretty much synonymous with a constructor and is invoked around the same time. componentDidMount will only be called once after the first render.

**componentWillMount --> render --> componentDidMount**

Comment: Thank you, but still I don't really know how to make it work

Comment: TRY TO USE componentWillMount instead componentDidMount

Comment: still nothing. It gives me warning "componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use." and my table stays empty

Comment: can u send the values of companies in parent component?